# How to store objects with an expiry date

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, .net-core, cache-expiration

I'm designing an ASP.net core system that deals with objects having an expiry date (2 days OR 1-3 months). Once this expiry date reached, expired objects should be removed.

We are using SQL + a Cron job to remove old items. That's not really efficient and we need to maintain the associated code.

I was considering using Redis for that purpose. However I'm not sure a recommended approach. Redis not persist the data so if we reboot the server we loose everything.

Any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Cache solutions with a built in TTL (Time to Live) will most likely work for you.

Redis does have persistence options that will preserve your data during a restart.

Have a look at - https://redis.io/commands/ttl
and https://redis.io/topics/persistence